# Drupal 6: Access Denied on custom module

Tags: module, drupal-6

I have this module, as admin users I can access this module normally. But when I add permission to other roles (and it saved), other users who have the permimssion couldn't access it. Please help me.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
include_once(drupal_get_path('module', 'tb') .'/tb.menu.inc');
include_once(drupal_get_path('module', 'tb') .'/tb.inc');

function tb_perm() {
  global $user;
  return array('trial_balance');
}

function tb_menu() {
  global $user;
  $items = array();

  $items['akuntansi/tb'] = array(
    'title' => 'Trial Balance',
  'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'page callback' => 'tb_neracapage',
    'file' => 'tb.inc',
    'access arguments' => array('akuntansi'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    //'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  $items['akuntansi/tb/pdf'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'tb_neracapage_pdf',
    'file' => 'tb.inc',
    'access arguments' => array('akuntansi'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
$items['akuntansi/tb/xls'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'tb_neracapage_xls',
    'file' => 'tb.inc',
    'access arguments' => array('akuntansi'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was here:

return array('trial_balance');

I should be:

return array('akuntansi');